# JavaScript currency conversions

Tags: javascript, currency

I am learning JavaScript, and I would like to learn more about using JavaScript to handle money.  I understand that numbers have to be scaled before performing arithmetic on them.  The thing I'd like to learn more about is converting amounts of money from one currency to another.  For example, maybe the currency of U.S. is converted to another country's currency.  My problem is that I can't find any information on this subject.  I've found a few API's for currency conversion, but I have to pay before I can even use them.  I was hoping that there would be something like a tutorial, or maybe a currency conversion chart for developers which plainly describes the conversions.

Thanks in advance.  =P

Comment: [This might be of use](http://oohhyeah.blogspot.com/2009/01/google-currency-conversion-api.html) (it's a currency converting API from Google) Edit: You might also be able to query XE.com using a similar method)

Comment: for what situation do you need the converting form on currency to another ? (just to test/display, for an online shop) ?

Comment: I'm just looking to learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to use JavaScript + jQuery + AJAX + PHP + MySQL.

Since it is the matter of currency conversion, you should be aware of dynamic changes in exchange rates. So you should keep a database of updated exchange rates. You may use MySQL for this. Then you may pass the parameters to a server side scripting service like PHP or ASP. This script can be used to pass arguments to database and retrieve data from them. jQuery along with AJAX can be used to pass user input from HTML page to PHP/ASP script file. And the Task is done!

Here are some tutorials.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that the currency conversion should be done on the server-side, or is it okay to do it on the client-side?

Comment: Using all that just to do simple arithmetic and formatting (i.e. "using JavaScript to handle money") is overkill.

Comment: @RobG, What do you suggest?

Comment: @JaPerk14 I think it will be fine if the conversion is calculated in server side and delivered to the browser. Otherwise, you may need to change the user interface page's script (JavaScript) each time, which is comparatively difficult.

Comment: @JaPerk14—the OP is asking for how to do it using javascript as an exercise. In that case, the client just loads the functions to do conversion and formatting, plus a conversion table (which might be a single object). All that is required is plain old JS, it doesn't even need AJAX, even to load a new conversion table object every time. Any serious conversion (e.g. for a shop) should use a server side process and probably leave it entirely to the payment gateway unless the site is prepared to wear the cost of small under/over conversion differences with the gateway.